# Temporary and expression behavior

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, temporary

Is this well defined behavior?

```
const char* p = (std::string("Hello") + std::string("World")).c_str();
std::cout << p;
```

I am not sure. Reasons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is undefined behavior. Both `std::string` temporaries and the temporary returned by `operator+` only live until the end of the initialization of your `const char*` (end of full expression). Then they are destroyed and `p` points to uncertain memory.

Comment: Everyone upvotes @Johannes only (even though @Prasoon has quoted the reference). Very unfair. :P

Comment: @Nawaz:  To quote Herb Sutter, "the standard is not a tutorial intended for real people to read."  Unless someone expressly requests a citation from the spec or the subject is so technical as to require references, it's best to leave the spec out of answers.  Just copying a paragraph with no explanation (what the heck is "an initializer for a declarator defining an object"?) is not particularly helpful.

Comment: @James: Are you saying one who quotes spec doesn't explain his answer? Are you saying every paragraph from the Standard is difficult to understand for *real people* and hence needs explanation?

Comment: @James : I dont think the sentence "In that context, the temporary that holds the result of the expression **shall persist until the object’s initialization is complete**." needs any explanation.
BTW you are right about copying stuffs from the Standard and gaining rep. ;-)

Comment: @Prasoon: There is nothing wrong in quoting from the Standard and gaining rep, if the entire post provides sound explanation, and the quotation just backs it up and enhances its quality.

Comment: @Nawaz:  I said neither of those things.  I am arguing that your statement "very unfair" is patently false and that "quoting the reference" is neither necessary nor sufficient to have a good answer.  In many cases, quoting one or two sentences does more harm than good. @Prasoon: There is a lot of background information required to understand that one sentence (why is this specific part relevant, what is a "full expression," what is a "declarator defining an object" vs. just a "declaration"?) The answer is clear enough without the citation; adding the quote only adds confusion.

Comment: @James: It looks like you took my words *"very unfair"* very unfairly :P.... By the way, I would like to know what problem do you find in @Prasoon's quotation from the spec? Also, an answer doesn't has to be for the OP only, but for SO users in general. Even those who already know the answer, can benefit from the post, if they see the citation. Ask yourself, how many times did such citation help you to enhance your knowledge of C++ in general?

Answer (score 2):

No the behaviour is undefined because `p` points to deallocated storage in `std::cout << p;`

A temporary is created to hold `std::string("Hello") + std::string("World")`. C-style string is then retrived from that object. At the end of the expression that temporary is destroyed leaving `p` pointing to a deallocated storage.

Using `p` then invokes Undefined Behavior.

12.2/4 says

> There  are  two  contexts  in  which  temporaries  are  destroyed  at  a  different  point  than  the  end  of  the  full-expression.  The  first  context  is when an expression appears as an initializer for a declarator defining an object.  In that context, the temporary that holds the result of the expression shall persist until the object’s
>   initialization is complete.
>   ....

Comment: The bit you've highlighted isn't obviously relevant. The temporary that holds the result of the expression used as initializer, is the temporary of type `const char*` that contains the return value from `c_str()`. What you've quoted says *that* temporary persists until initialization is complete, it doesn't say that all temporaries in the expression (including the strings) persist until initialization is complete...

Comment: ... although I think that's implied elsewhere, maybe something about temporaries being destroyed in reverse order of creation? Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

it won't compile because of a missing semi-colon:

```
const char* p = (std::string("Hello") + std::string("World")).c_str(); //<< important here
std::cout << p;
```

NOW the rule applies that the temporary is deleted at the end of the expression it is used in, which is at the semicolon. So you have a pointer to deleted memory which causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I recently read this excellent book http://www.amazon.co.uk/Gotchas-Avoiding-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0321125185/ref and if I recall correctly this is pretty much one of the examples given there.

I believe the data returned from `c_str` is only valid as long as the string object that returned it is live. The string objects in your example are only live for the duration of the expression.